# Как сделать однократное добавление новой кнопки?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Проблема в том, что если нажать на кнопку (1) появляется другая кнопка (2), а при повторном нажатии на кнопку (1) рядом с кнопкой (2) появляются еще кнопки (2), а надо чтобы появлялась только одна кнопка(2) и не дублировалась.

```
$(html).appendTo('#body');
$('#knopka_1').click(function () {
    form_i();
})
```

То есть при нажатии на кнопку (1) вызывается функция, где прописана кнопка (2).

P.S. Это JavaScript.

Comment: полностью код скиньте. Возможно, что у вас в функции form_i() прописано добавление обработчика на #knopka_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отключите обработчик после срабатывания события. Например, так:

```
$('#knopka_1').click(function () {
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

Comment: Это не есть решение проблемы, а только костыль для неё.

Comment: Для озвученной проблемы - это решение.

Comment: А почему бы дальше не пойти? ))) Тут не паханное поле для костылей. Вот еще решение:

    $('#knopka_1').one('click', function () {
        form_i();
    });